# Scope of column names, aliases, and OUT parameters in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a hard time understanding why I can refer to the output columns in `returns table(col type)`.

There is a subtle bug in the below code, the `order by` var refers to `res` in `returns`, not to `data1` which we aliased to `res`. `res` in `where` is always null and we get 0 rows.

Why can I refer to the column name in output?
In what cases do I want this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(var INTEGER)
RETURNS table(res int )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    return query 
    select data1 res 
    from table_with_data 
    where res < var;
end
$function$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why can I refer to the column name in output

From [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), the section about function parameters:

> *column_name* The name of an output column in the RETURNS TABLE syntax. This is effectively another way of declaring a named OUT parameter, except that RETURNS TABLE also implies RETURNS SETOF.

What this means is that in your case `res` is effectively a writeable variable, which type you plan to return a set of. As any other variable without a default value assigned, it starts off as `null`.

### In what case do I want this

You can return multiple records from a function of this type with a single `return query`, but [another](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) way is by a series of multiple `return query` or `return next` - in the second case, filling out the fields in a record of your output table each time. You could have expected a return statement to end the function, but in this scenario only a single `return;` without anything added would have that effect.

```sql
create table public.test_res (data integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(var INTEGER)
RETURNS table(res int )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    insert into public.test_res select res;--to inspect its initial value later
    select 1 into res;
    return next;
    return next;--note that res isn't reset after returning next
    return query select 2;--doesn't affect the current value of res
    return next;--returning something else earlier didn't affect res either
    return;--it will finish here
    select 3 into res;
    return next;
end
$function$;
select * from test(0);
-- res
-------
--   1
--   1
--   2
--   1
--(4 rows)
table public.test_res; --this was the initial value of res within the function
-- data
--------
-- null
--(1 row)
```

Which is the most useful with [`LOOP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS)s

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(var INTEGER)
RETURNS table(comment text,res int) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
declare  rec record;
         array_slice int[];
begin
    return query select 'return query returned these multiple records in one go', a from generate_series(1,3,1) a(a);
    res:=0;
    comment:='loop exit when res>4';
    loop exit when res>4;
        select res+1 into res;
        return next;
    end loop;
    comment:='while res between 5 and 8 loop';
    while res between 5 and 8 loop
      select res+2 into res;
      return next;
    end loop;
    comment:='for element in reverse 3 .. -3 by 2 loop';
    for element in reverse 3 .. -3 by 2 loop
      select element into res;
      return next;
    end loop;
    comment:='for <record> in <expression> loop';
    for rec in select pid from pg_stat_activity where state<>'idle' loop
      select rec.pid into res;
      return next;
    end loop;
    comment:='foreach array_slice slice 1 in array arr loop';
    foreach array_slice SLICE 1 in array ARRAY[[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]] loop
      select array_slice[1] into res;
      return next;
    end loop;
end
$function$;
```

Example results

```sql
select * from public.test(0);
--                        comment                         |  res
----------------------------------------------------------+--------
-- return query returned these multiple records in one go |      1
-- return query returned these multiple records in one go |      2
-- return query returned these multiple records in one go |      3
-- loop exit when res>4                                   |      1
-- loop exit when res>4                                   |      2
-- loop exit when res>4                                   |      3
-- loop exit when res>4                                   |      4
-- loop exit when res>4                                   |      5
-- while res between 5 and 8 loop                         |      7
-- while res between 5 and 8 loop                         |      9
-- for element in reverse 3 .. -3 by 2 loop               |      3
-- for element in reverse 3 .. -3 by 2 loop               |      1
-- for element in reverse 3 .. -3 by 2 loop               |     -1
-- for element in reverse 3 .. -3 by 2 loop               |     -3
-- for <record> in <expression> loop                      | 118786
-- foreach array_slice slice 1 in array arr loop          |      1
-- foreach array_slice slice 1 in array arr loop          |     11
-- foreach array_slice slice 1 in array arr loop          |     21
--(18 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

True, `OUT` parameters (including field names in a `RETURNS TABLE (...)` clause) are visible in all SQL DML statements in a PL/pgSQL function body, just like other variables. Find details in the manual chapters [Variable Substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST) and [Returning from a Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) for PL/pgSQL.

**However**, a more fundamental misunderstanding comes first here. The syntax of your nested `SELECT` is invalid to begin with. The PL/pgSQL variable happens to mask this problem (with a different problem). In SQL, you cannot refer to output column names (column aliases in the `SELECT` clause) in the `WHERE` clause. This is invalid:

```
select data1 res 
from table_with_data 
where res < var;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
> `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses;
> there you must write out the expression instead.

This is different for `ORDER BY`, which you mention in the text, but don't include in the query. See:

- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

#### Fixing immediate issue

Could be repaired like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test1(var int)
  RETURNS TABLE(res int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT data1 AS res     -- column alias is just noise (or documentation)
   FROM   table_with_data
   WHERE  data1 < var;     -- original column name!
END
$func$
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nrWZOW6E)

See:

- [Real number comparison for trigram similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954707/real-number-comparison-for-trigram-similarity/73954791#73954791)

The column alias is just noise in this case. The name of the column returned from the function is `res` in any case - as defined in the `RETURNS TABLE` clause.

Aside: It's recommended not to omit the `AS` keyword for column aliases (unlike table aliases). See:

- [Query to ORDER BY the number of rows returned from another SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229979/query-to-order-by-the-number-of-rows-returned-from-another-select/20230716#20230716)

**If** there was actual ambiguity between column and variable name - say, you declared an `OUT` parameter or variable named `data1` - you'd get an error message like this:

```
ERROR:  column reference "data1" is ambiguous
LINE 2:    select data1 
                  ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
```

#### Brute force fix

Could be fixed with a special command at the start of the function body:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test3(var int)
  RETURNS TABLE(data1 int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
#variable_conflict use_column  -- ! to resolve conflicts
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT data1
   FROM   table_with_data
   WHERE  data1 < var;         -- !
END
$func$
```

See:

- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105902/3684)

#### Proper fix

Table-qualify column names, and avoid conflicting variable names to begin with.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test4(_var int)
  RETURNS TABLE(res int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t.data1            -- table-qualify column name
   FROM   table_with_data t
   WHERE  t.data1 < _var;    -- !
END
$func$
```

Example:

- [Calling a PostgreSQL function from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483219/calling-a-postgresql-function-from-java/15484437#15484437)